# How do I rename the values in when I read pandas csv file

Tags: python, pandas, rename

When I read the csv file, **in one command line**, how do I rename the values ?

```
df = pd.read_csv('aaa.csv')
```

I want to see this data frame

```
Hobby  Sex  No  
0   0   12345

0     1     67788

0     1     0909

1     1     5867433
```

to convert like this new values.

```
Hobby      Sex       No 

Travel    Female    12345

Travel     Male     67788

Travel     Male     0909


Dance      Male     5867433
```

Comment: Don't use file as a variable

Comment: @Boud I don't know much about handling csv in Python, but what's wrong with that? For normal files, `f = open("stuff.txt", 'r')` is perfectly fine, so what is wrong with `df = pd.read_csv('aaa.csv')`?

Comment: This is my edited version, OP was file= and superseding the file function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`read_csv` DOCS](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

> **converters** : `dict`, default `None`
>   Dict of functions for converting values in certain columns. Keys can either be integers or column labels

***demonstration***

```
converters = dict(Hobby=lambda x: {'0': 'Travel', '1': 'Dance'}[x],
                  Sex=lambda x: {'0': 'Female', '1': 'Male'}[x])

df = pd.read_csv('aaa.csv', converters=converters)

df
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! What is the [x] do after the lambda function??

Comment: It's getting the x from the dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Use a dict with the mappings and apply each dict to the corresponding column:

```
df['Hobby'] = df.Hobby.map({0:'Travel', 1:'Dance'})
df
Out[52]: 
    Hobby  Sex       No
0  Travel    0    12345
1  Travel    1    67788
2  Travel    1      909
3   Dance    1  5867433
```